# magit-stage-modified doesn't stage untracked files

Tags: magit

When I want to stage one file I use the command `magit-stage`. It works.

But now I want to stage many files at once, using the command `magit-stage-modified`.

Here's a  sceenshot:

[image: Magit-stage-modified]

But after I press <kbd>y</kbd> nothing happens. All files stay in the **Untracked files** section.

Answer (score 8):

`magit-stage-modified` only stages modified files. Files that are not being tracked by git are not modified. Here "modified" means "there are changes compared to the changes in the index". Files that are not even being tracked are not in the index.

You can stage all untracked files by moving the cursor to `Untracked files (5)` and pressing <kbd>s</kbd>. Or you could invoke `magit-stage-modified` with a prefix argument - in that case it also stages untracked files.

You should also read [Getting Started](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Getting-Started.html) in the manual, which among other things, describes various ways to stage changes.

Comment: For those wondering: you can issue the prefix argument from magit status as per, using `C-u`. So the full sequence would be `C-x g C-u S`.